# Как считывать файл по 64 символа? C++ ifstream

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Всем привет, как мне считывать файл по 64 символа?
Вот пример части кода где происходить считывание, там остальное все обычное вроде открыть файл посчитать размер и тд.

```
    read_size_ = read_size;
    current_pos_ = 0;
    file_ = std::make_unique<std::ifstream>(path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);

    if (!file_->is_open())
        std::cout << "Error: can't open file\n" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "File was open\n" << std::endl;

    buff_.reserve(read_size+1);

    file_size_ = file_->seekg(0, std::ios::end).tellg();
    file_->seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
```

---

```
std::vector<char> buff;

buff.clear();
    if(file_size_ > read_size_)
    {
        std::cout << "READ_SIZE: " << read_size_ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "FILE_SIZE: " << file_size_ << std::endl;
        file_->seekg(current_pos_);
        file_->read(buff.data(), read_size_);
        buff[read_size_] = 0;
        current_pos_ += read_size_;
        out_buff(buff);
    }

    if (*file_)
        std::cout << "all characters read successfully.";
    else
        std::cout << "error: only " << file_->gcount() << " could be read";
```

мой вывод, очевидно неправильный:

```
File was open

READ_SIZE: 64
FILE_SIZE: 1651
---------------- SIZE: 0 ----------------
---------------- END OUT ----------------
---------------- SIZE: 0 ----------------
---------------- END OUT ----------------
all characters read successfully.
```

функция вывода на всякий случай но врядли в ней проблема:

```
void out_buff(std::vector<char> buff)
{
    std::cout << "---------------- SIZE: " << buff.size() << " ----------------" << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < buff.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << buff[i];
    }

    std::cout << "---------------- END OUT ----------------" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Вы нигде не устанавливаете размер буфера. Или просто выкинули код из примера?

Comment: @Chorkov добавил в вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не понимаю как приведенные фрагменты кода вообще работают. Объявление нового вектора:

```
std::vector<char> buff;
```

потом зачем-то его очищение

```
buff.clear();
```

потом чтение в пустой вектор:

```
file_->read(buff_.data(), read_size_);
```

есть **UB**. Подозреваю, что в работавшем примере использовался `buff_`.
Вывод в `out_buff` идет в цикле от 0 до `buff.size()`, но в буфер нигде не добавляли элементы. `reserve` меняет `capacity`, а не `size`, надо использовать `resize`.
Для чтения блоками можно использовать такой код:

```
  std::vector<char> buff_;
  buff_.resize(read_size_ + 1);

  while (file_)
  {
    file_->read(buff_.data(), read_size_);

    //Проверим сколько считали.
    size_t count = file_->gcount();
    if (!count)
      break;

    //buff_[read_size_] = 0;
    out_buff(buff_, count);
  }
```

Этот код считывает файл блоками размера `read_size_` с учетом того, что размер файла может быть негранулярным этому размеру, т.е. последнее чтение считает
меньше `read_size_`.
Считанные данные не используются как строка, непонятно зачем выдлеять массив на 1 больше чем размер чтения и зачем писать после чтения туда 0.
Если он должен использоваться как строка, надо раскомментировать запись нуля и заменить на `buff_[count] = 0;`.

Не следует передавать в функцию вывода копии вектора, это непроизводительно. Вместо этого const ссылка. Ну и с учетом того что могут считать блок меньшего размера, передаем в функцию и выводимый размер:

```
void out_buff(const std::vector<char>& buff, size_t count)
{
  std::cout << "---------------- SIZE: " << buff.size() << " ----------------" << std::endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    std::cout << buff[i];
  }

  std::cout << "---------------- END OUT ----------------" << std::endl;
}
```